# Executing a variable with a pipe in shell

Tags: shell, variables, pipe

I have a command that I need to use repeatedly within a shell script. This is command contains a pipe and the output of the whole command will be piped to other commands.

e.g. Let's say for simplicity sake the command is `ls | tee`. Then I might pipe it to other commands, says `ls | tee | someprogram` or `ls | tee | anotherprogram`.

So naturally I'll want to keep `ls | tee` is a variable. The problem is that I can't seem to execute a variable with a pipe in it.

```
#!/bin/sh
TEST="ls | tee"
$TEST
```

Gives the following output

```
ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access tee: No such file or directory
```

How do I execute a variable like `$TEST` above, whist being able to pipe the output to other commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is `eval`.

```
eval $TEST somefile

eval $TEST otherfile | more
```

However, you need to be aware that `eval` means problems with quoting special characters and blanks and the like.  If everything is simple (`TEST="ls -l | tee"`), then it is easy.  If you have spaces in arguments or shell metacharacters, then it is hard — very hard — to do it right.  At that point, you'd be better off creating a function or separate shell script.

You might well be better off with a function or shell script even so.

If the string you `eval` comes from a user, you have to worry even more!

Comment: +1 I second the recommendation to use a function, not a variable, in the script: `TEST() { ls | tee; }; TEST | grep bar`